# Connecting to SQL Server database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database in my website. I have created a database from Add -> Add New Item -> SQL Server database. The name of my database file is `database.mdf`.

I have created a ConnectionString:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Khulna_website"
         connectionString= "Server=(localDB)\\v11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=Database.mdf;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My first question is, when I open a database that way, is it necessary to add a connection string? Asking that because I can already see a green connection line on the side of the database.

Then, how do I connect it on my C# code?

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
```

The question is, what do I add on `["RegistrationConnectionString"]` part? Should I give the name of my ConnectionString? Am I missing any point here? I am completely new here. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in order to connect to a database - you do need some form of a connection string - one way or another. It's typically considered a best practice to put those connection strings into a config file, so you can modify it without changing your code.

To retrieve the actual connection string from the config, you need to use the `name=....` to you gave it in the config file:

```
<add name="Khulna_website"
           ***************  this is the **name** of your connection string
```

Retrieve it like this:

```
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Khulna_website"].ConnectionString;
                                                        ************** same name again
```

and then use it to create your connection object to the database:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Put the name of the connection string which is `Khulna_website` instead of `RegistrationConnectionString`